# ng-model data bing not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to update a field with a new geo code value, but even though the model is updated it is not binding with first call.  My controller code is as follows:

```
function TheReportCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.code = [];
    $scope.code.lat = "19.2555500";
    $scope.getCode = function () {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = "12323 Barker Cypress Rd, Cypress, Texas"
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $scope.code.lat = results[0].geometry.location.k;
            } else {
                console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is the missing part of my code?

[Here is the JsFiddle Code Sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gayancc/7v2dfLsv/)

Comment: You need to call `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.code.lat = results[0].geometry.location.k;`. AngularJS does not know you changed the scope otherwise.

Comment: thanks  Sergiu Paraschiv unfortunately your answer is in comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually working, you just need to update the `$scope` by using the `$apply()` method. Here's a fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7v2dfLsv/3/

Comment: Change $scope.apply() to $scope.$apply() and it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed an 
$scope().$apply();

See http://fiddle.jshell.net/yfLek2cw/

Also your Angular CDNLink inside your original fiddle doesn't work. The reason is, that the geolocation callback is done not from angular. Therefore the dirty check mechanism doesn't work there. To start the dirty check again, you've to call $scope.$apply();

This is needed for ALL external callback functions, even if those callbacks are inside the angular scope. Auto $apply only works for angular callbacks like $timeout or the $q service